# Code for a single screen app. But it only shows the text and not the image

Tags: android

I have tried different combinations of nested layout. It does show it when I change image layout_height from "0dp" to “wrap content” but it only works for some devices and shows black screen which is the remaining space below.
It is single page app showing a picture of bicycle on top followed by a relative text view as shown in the links to the images below
Can anyone help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linear"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0a0a0a"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.sachinpatil.bicyclesnation.MainActivity">

<ImageView

    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/bike" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:fontFamily="georgia"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/first"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/location" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textView3"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/phoneIcon" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/second"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#e8e6e6" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@id/textView2"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:text="@string/third"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textColor="#e8e6e6" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView5"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/fourth"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse"
        android:textColor="#fff" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/textView6"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/fifth"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sixth"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[This is the link to the output of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcFAe.jpg)

[NewOutputImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiDv3.jpg)

Comment: Why are you guys downvoting the question, I have tried a lot solving it

Answer (score 1):

Probably your **problem** is in this line:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

**Try set**:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

**The problem**:

You are set height to 0 so image don't have height. when you run the app image not shows.

Comment: I want to expand the image to cover the blank screen by setting layout_weight. Wrap content fixs the layout height

Comment: I don't see your blank screen in image but you have two ways, one the blank screen is a linearLayout, and put the image inside the blank linearlayout or set a height diferent than 0 for exemple 100dp

Comment: First thanks for replying. I did as you said but now there is space between the image and text. I wanted to set layout_weight on image so that it could change its dimensions according to the screen size

Comment: So what you did change image height or put image inside a linearLayout?

Comment: image height to wrap content and added one more linearlayout for the image.

Comment: So if you put image inside a LinearLayout set image height to match_parent and LinearLayout of image to height you want for exemple 200dp.

Comment: If you don't add image inside a linearlayout just set image height to wath you want for exemple 200dp

Comment: Yeah it worked but only for one device. My question is how to change it dynamically with screen size. Once again thanks

Comment: use percentage for exemple 20% is something like this **android:layout_height="20"**